# Azure DevOps Pipeline Release using SSH Task Connection Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use Azure Pipeline Release to setup a project deployment on a VM server running on linux using SSH connection but keeps getting this error message:

**`Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake.`**

This is also running on a self-hosted agent.

Used the private key generated from the server to set-up the SSH Service Connection. Was able to successfully access the VM with my local machine using ssh connection as well.

Comment: Verify that the agent can access the VM (e.g. check networking security rules, ports, firewall etc).

Comment: Yes, was using my local machine as the self-hosted agent. Can access the VM locally with the same ssh connection so I thought the problem might not be there.